# How to save Quote item using plugin?

Tags: magento2

I have created one plugin where user will add product to the cart at that time need to change product name which will show in cart, mini-cart, checkout and all order section.

I have created below plugin

```
namespace [VENDOR]\[MODULNAME]\Plugin\Quote\Model\Quote;

class Item 
{
    public function afterSetProduct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item $subject,
        $result
    ){
        $subject->getProduct()->setName('New Name');
    }
}
```

above code is change name in cart and mini cart but not in checkout and all order section how to do this product name change in all.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if your code is really executed?
In Checkout, data is taken from webapi, so the area code in this case is not frontend anymore, it's "webapi_rest". So if your related di.xml is located in frontend directory, this is not called, you've to add your plugin also in webapi_rest/di.xml